# Why is <s> not listed as Phrasing Content on MDN?

Tags: html, specifications

On the page about [Content Categories on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories), the tags `<b>` and `<i>` are listed under both "phrasing content" and "flow content".

The pages for `<b>` and `<i>` both list them as phrasing **and** flow content, whereas the `<s>` tag lists "Phrasing content **or** flow content" (emphasis mine). However, there's no note on the Content Categories page that clarifies this, and I cannot find the `<s>` element in the HTML5 specification, despite MDN not marking it as obsolete or deprecated.

Is this just a mistake on MDN's part, or is the `<s>` element poorly defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a mistake or inconsistency on MDN's part. [W3C HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-s-element) and [WHATWG HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-s-element) both clearly list the `<s>` element under §4.5 Text-level semantics as flow content, phrasing content, and palpable content, exactly as they do with the `<b>` and `<i>` elements.

Comment: Interesting. Comparing the MDN article to https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#elements-1, there are a lot of inconsistencies...

Comment: @Erty Seidohl: MDN is by no means an official or authoritative source for HTML and CSS, and it does unfortunately suffer from a number of inconsistencies and outdated information.

Comment: *screams internally*

Comment: Oh, yeah. I didn't actually see that. I'll submit some changes to bring it up to spec.

Comment: @Erty Seidohl: You the real MVP, all I ever use as references anymore are W3C/WHATWG specs. Straight from the horse's mouth.